# Laravel subconsultas en query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de entender como crear consultas con subconsultas en Query Builder. El problema es que la documentación oficial es extremadamente escueta y poco explicativa en algunos puntos específicos. En concreto, los métodos `joinSub()` y `raw()` no es que estén especialmente detallados, y todo lo que encuentro en blogs y en otros sitios son meras copias (originales o traducidas), de la docu, pero no aportan explicaciones adicionales.

Tengo esta consulta en SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM articles AS tabla, (SELECT MIN(created_at) AS minimo 
FROM articles) AS sub WHERE tabla.created_at = sub.minimo
```

Como veis, se trata de recuperar los registros con la fecha de creación más antigua. Sé que hay otros modos más sencillos de hacer esto, pero la consulta la creado para explorar las subconsultas con Query Builder y con Eloquent.

Os agradecería que no me dijerais como debe quedar la consulta de ejemplo que he puesto, si no que me indicarais dónde encontrar información más detallada sobre estos dos métodos en particular, porque lo que necesito es entender el funcionamiento.

Comment: revisa el ejemplo de este sitio web https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-how-to-make-subquery-in-select-statementexample.html

Comment: Es un buen comienzo. Aunque no usa el método `joinSub()` ni se detiene a explicar la operativa de `raw()`. Además, las subconsultas las inserta directamente, como cadenas SQL. En tu opinión, puede esta ser una solución adecuada? Es evidente que de Laravel dominas mucho más que yo. Si crees que es una buena solución, me fío de tu experiencia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ante la duda en las supuestas falencias de la documentación, siempre se puede revisar el código fuente de laravel y ver lo que hacen dichos métodos.

Comment: Si, te lo agradezco, Shaz. Es algo que hago con frecuencia. Con algunos es fácil de rastrear y seguir, casi los pillas al primer vistazo, pero con otros cuesta bastante más. De todos modos, gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 1):

Usa:
`DB::raw()`

Aquí hay un ejemplo de la documentación oficial de Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions

```
DB::table('articles')
->select('articles.*', DB::raw('SELECT MIN(created_at) AS minimo FROM articles')) AS minimo 
->where('articles.created_at', '=' 'sub.minimo')->get();
```

Quedaría algo así, perdón lo hice mas rápido que puedo a ojo de buen cubero espero y te pueda ayudar o alguien mas